# Set the browser min zoom level below 25%

Tags: browser, zooming

Chrome, Firefox and Opera don't let the user set the browser zoom level below 25%, so far as I can tell. I want to set it below 25%. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set the browser zoom level below 25% in most browsers, but there is a way to do much the same thing, as a developer. When you create an HTML canvas, you set the size of the canvas with the width and height attributes, canvas.width and canvas.height. The CSS properties, canvas.style.width and canvas.style.height, only set the size at which the canvas is displayed, not the size of the canvas itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd put an answer here for anyone looking on Firefox;

Go to about:config
Search 'zoom'

Set zoom.minPercent to the minimum % zoom you would like to set